# Django - AdminDateWidget

Tags: django, forms, date, widget, range

I'm using Django and the AdminDateWidget in my form. It works fine. But now I've to level up my form.

I need to insert only a range of date with this widget. The range would be limited in the future, this mean I have to remove the possibility of insert a date after today.

Is it possible? This is my form's code. (it's a dynamic form for having always a refreshed date)

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, name, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirstStartMiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['insertion_date'] = forms.DateField(widget = widgets.AdminDateWidget(), initial=date.today())
        ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about form validations here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Here is a suggestion:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def clean_insertion_date(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['insertion_date'] > date.today():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Time travel are we?")
```